# Roundcube on Nginx + php-fpm

Tags: nginx, centos, php, roundcube

I am running a VPS server with Centos and Plesk.
The server is working right, on a Nginx + php-fpm setup.

So, websites are served correctly, but when user tries to access to its webemail ( roundcube tool installed ), doesn't work.

My current nginx conf for webmail is :

```
server {
    listen [my server ip...]:80;
    server_name webmail.* roundcube.webmail.* horde.webmail.* atmail.webmail.*;

   client_max_body_size 20m;
   client_body_buffer_size 128k;
   proxy_read_timeout 90;


location / {
               root /usr/share/psa-roundcube;
               index index.php index.html index.htm;

    location ~ \.php$ 
               {    
                        fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
                        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
                        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                    fastcgi_keep_conn on;
            fastcgi_split_path_info       ^(.+\.php)(.*)$;
        }
        }
}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This snippet works for me on CentOS 6.5. The `SCRIPT_FILENAME` is different and the is `fastcgi_index` is present. Think that's it.

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
}
```

I have copied it from [here](http://www.howtoforge.com/running-roundcube-0.7.1-on-nginx-lemp-on-debian-squeeze-ubuntu-11.10) and it works. The other directives in this particular example are very worth to get noticed/copied to harden the plesk setup just a little.